# Can a .pfx file contain more than one private key?

Tags: key-management

I am trying to understand whether .pfx file may contain multiple private keys or not.

In case there are several sets of certificates and their private keys how they can be found in KeyStore? By using aliases, right?

Comment: What KeyStore ? PKCS#12 file can, indeed, contains several private keys.

Comment: I second what Stephane said. What KeyStore? PFX files may contain all sorts of things. Think of it as a ZIP file to for crypto-related-stuff.

Comment: by KeyStore I meant Java's KeyStore or BC's Pkcs12Store classes.

Comment: You can lookup how to convert the pfx to pem, which is human readable, then you can verify for yourself. In general, the PKCS#12 format support multiple keys.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So the answer is yes it can have any number of private keys and associated certificates. Thank you guys.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: Ok, but I was going to accept this answer as a correct one. I will be able to do it tomorrow

Comment: Can you please send us procedure to add multiple private keys in one .p12 file