# .pfx with multiple PrivateKeyEntry not working in Postman - Error: MULTIPLE_PRIVATE_KEYS_IN_PKCS12

Tags: postman, keystore, private-key, pfx, pkcs#12

I'm trying to put all the different certificates in a single .pfx (PKCS12) file. I am able to import all the PrivateKeyEntry(s) in a master pfx file (also I verified the entries using keytool command - output snippet -

```
alias1, Sep 9, 2020,PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1):<XX:YY:...>
alias2, Sep 9, 2020,PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1):<AA:BB:...>
```

)
but when I'm using this pfx in Postman I'm getting "Error: MULTIPLE_PRIVATE_KEYS_IN_PKCS12"!
When I'm using certificates individually then everything is working fine in Postman. I checked already that multiple PrivateKeyEntry can reside in a single .pfx file - [Can a .pfx file contain more than one private key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694110/can-a-pfx-file-contain-more-than-one-private-key).

Instead of maintaining separate pfx files to connect separate systems I want to keep all certificate entries in a single file (pfx) so that can be used for all the different systems.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert pfx certificate into another format. Crt+key works for me.
You can use [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) to convert certificate:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out certificate.crt
openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.pfx -nocerts -out key-encrypted.key
```

Comment: I've to use the .pfx as per the industry standard. I don't want to change to other format.